# What is the equivalent for this in Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, castle-windsor

Supposing I have e.g.:

```
public interface IYetAnotherInterface : IMyBaseInterface
public class JustAClass: IYetAnotherInterface
```

using Unity DI container this is valid:

```
container.RegisterType<IMyBaseInterface, IYetAnotherInterface>();
container.RegisterType<IYetAnotherInterface, JustAClass>();
```

How can I do this using Castle Windsor? This fails:

```
container.Register(
   Component
      .For<IMyBaseInterface>()
      .ImplementedBy<IYetAnotherInterface >());

container.Register(
   Component
      .For<IYetAnotherInterface >()
      .ImplementedBy<JustAClass>());
```

I am trying to resolve the IYetAnotherInterface in a ctor, e.g.

```
public Foo(IYetAnotherInterface i, ...)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `it fails`?

Comment: While the registration is successful, when the _YetAnotherInterface_ tries to be resolved in some constructor, I am getting exception:

**Type _YetAnotherInterface_  is abstract.
As such, it is not possible to instansiate it as implementation of service 'YetAnotherInterface'. Did you forget to proxy it?**

Comment: `IYetAnotherInterface` is interface... you can not create an object of an interface. That's why you are seeing this error. Interface DI registration happens for the concrete class implementing the interface. So your first registration is not valid. The second one is valid.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Yes, I know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the `container.RegisterType<Interface1, Interface2>();` thing does in Unity. It looks like it hooks up the component for one to also resolve for the other?

If that's the case, you have two options.

- Go with what @vzwick's answer says if you want to have two components.
- Go with the following if you want just one component.

.

```
Component
   .For<IMyBaseInterface, IYetAnotherInterface>()
   .ImplementedBy<JustAClass>()
```

So in the first option you end up with two separate components, both backed by `JustAClass`, each exposing a single *service* interface: one for `IMyBaseInterface` and the other for `IYetAnotherInterface`.

In the second option you end up with a single component, exposing both `IMyBaseInterface` and `IYetAnotherInterface`.

[The documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/services-and-components.md) has a pretty good explanation of the concepts, and I highly recommend familiarising yourself with it.

Comment: "It looks like it hooks up the component for one to also resolve for the other?" . I think so, yes. Your solution is what I ended up doing to solve my problem. But what is the difference between this and @vzwick's answer?

Comment: I expanded the answer to discuss the differences, and provide a link to the documentation for a refresher on the concepts. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

```
container.Register(
    Component
      .For<IMyBaseInterface>()
      .ImplementedBy<JustAClass>());

container.Register(
    Component
      .For<IYetAnotherInterface >()
      .ImplementedBy<JustAClass>());
```

Actually, for your given scenario (a ctor with a dependency on `IYetAnotherInterface`), just the second registration should suffice.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I actually tried this as well as the answer from @krzysztof-kozmic, both are working fine for me. What is the difference though between the two answers?

Comment: Assuming you register the component as a Singleton, the answer @KrzysztofKozmic provided will resolve the same instance if you require `IMyBaseInterface` and `IYetAnotherInterface`. Mine would resolve two different instances. If your Component's lifetime is not singleton/scoped, both answers are equivalent.